# React add new props to cloned element with spread operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, properties, clone

I have a container like so:

```
const ReactContainer = ({ children, ...rest }) => React.cloneElement(children, rest);
```

Now, I want to add new props - `count` and `flag` - to the cloned elements:

So I tried this:

```
const ReactContainer = ({ children, ...rest }) => {
    const count = 0;
    const flag = false;

    return React.cloneElement(children, {count, flag}, rest);
};
```

But this doesn't work and I've tried other variations. How can I add these new props to the cloned elements keeping the spread operator for simplicity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try this:

```
const ReactContainer = ({ children, ...rest }) => {
    const count = 0;
    const flag = false;

    return React.cloneElement(children, {...rest, count, flag});
};
```

Please note that in above example `...rest` used in component function definition acts as [rest parameters syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) while in `cloneElement` it acts as [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator).